Perform a weighted linear regression on $x_i, y_i$ by doing a standard linear regression on $X_i, Y_i$?
Let's say we want to do a weighted linear regression between two series $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$, with weights $(w_i)$, and get the coefficients from the line $y = mx + p$, and the $r^2$ coefficient.
Is this process mathematically equivalent to performing a (non-weighted) linear regression between two series $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$, which can be easily expressed in terms of $x_i$, $y_i$, $w_i$ ?
i.e. can we turn a weighted linear regression problem into an equivalent problem with a standard linear regression with modified input series?
(Note: this question is purely theoretical, and here we don't focus on any programming)

Maybe this is helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/647146/why-are-1-se-or-1-variance-commonly-used-as-weights-in-regressions

Yes; weighted linear regression fit using weighted least squares involves minimizing the following objective function:
$$
\sum_i {w_i(y_i - b_0 - x_i b_1)^2}
$$
You might be able to see that this is equivalent to minimizing
$$
\sum_i {(\sqrt{w_i}y_i - \sqrt{w_i}b_0 - \sqrt{w_i}x_i b_1)^2}
$$
That means if you do a standard linear regression of $y$ on $x$ after multiplying them by $\sqrt{w}$, including $\sqrt{w}$ as a predictor in lieu of the intercept, you can get the same results. Below is an example in R:
# Use lalonde data from cobalt
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

y <- lalonde$re78
x <- lalonde$re74

# Generate random weights from Chi(2) distribution
set.seed(123)
w <- rchisq(length(x), 2)

# Weighted model
coef(fit1 <- lm(y ~ 1 + x, weights = w))
#>  (Intercept)            x 
#> 4497.4804324    0.4547541

# Transform variables
rw <- sqrt(w)
yw <- y * rw
xw <- x * rw

# Regression on transformed variables
coef(fit2 <- lm(yw ~ 0 + rw + xw))
#>           rw           xw 
#> 4497.4804324    0.4547541


all.equal(coef(fit1), coef(fit2),
          check.attributes = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2024-06-16 with reprex v2.1.0
The two strategies yield the same coefficients estimates. Indeed, this is how R performs weighted linear regression internally. Note the standard errors might differ between the two approaches.

+1 though note that the reported $r^2$ may be different compared to the weighted regression, partly because of the "no intercept" requirement.

Thank you very much @Noah! Out of curiosity, would you have an idea for https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/649463/prediction-bands-for-weighted-linear-regression?

Yes - if the weights are rational multiples of each other.
By multiplying through by a common denominator you can turn the weights into integers, and then treat them as repeated observations and apply ordinary linear regression to get the same coefficients and $r^2$ as with weighted linear regression.
Tests of significance will not be meaningful this way as you have implicitly artificially increased the sample size with these repeated observations and probably made things seem more significant than they really are: xkcd illustrated a similar issue.
Take for example in R, the weighted linear regression:
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(7,10,9)
w <- c(0.5, 0.2, 0.3)
weightedfit <- lm(y ~ x, weights=w) 
summary(weightedfit) 

showing
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, weights = w)

Weighted Residuals:
      1       2       3 
-0.2233  0.7061 -0.2883 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   6.2105     1.8232   3.406    0.182
x             1.1053     0.9116   1.212    0.439

Residual standard error: 0.7947 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5951,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1903 
F-statistic:  1.47 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.4391

and compare this to the ordinary linear regression with replication based on the weights multiplied by their common denominator of $10$.
repx <- rep(x, w*10)
repy <- rep(y, w*10)
replicatededfit <- lm(repy ~ repx) 
summary(replicatededfit) 

showing
Call:
lm(formula = repy ~ repx)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5263 -0.4737 -0.3158 -0.3158  1.5790 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   6.2105     0.6446   9.635 1.12e-05 ***
repx          1.1053     0.3223   3.429  0.00896 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8885 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5951,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5445 
F-statistic: 11.76 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.008964

where you can see that the coefficient estimates $(6.2105$ and $1.1053$) and the R-squared $(0.5951)$ are the same both times, though little else is.

Thank you! Very clever indeed :)  In the case they are not rational multiples of each other (we could always do an approximation with rational numbers, but let's say we want to avoid this trick), would there be another way?

Ultimate goal @Henry: I need to use Excel, and Excel has LINEST for standard linear regression (which gives everything: slope/intercept, r², F statistic, standard errors, etc. which is supe rhandy). Unfortunately, Excel doesn't have weighted linear regression, that's why I wanted to know if there is a trick to transform a weighted regression (for example with 1/s²) into a "normal" one for which I could use Excel's LINEST.

@Basj: Noah's answer gives another way which deals with both of your further questions. Note that with Noah's answer (a) you then have to tell R or Excel not to have an intercept; (b) you are using a second so-called independent variable; and (c) the reported $r^2$ will change.
